dask 2024.5.2 has no such extra feature 'diskcache'
I am getting this on MacOS (M2 Pro) when running a python program.
Mint.py
/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/bin/Mint.py:4: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html                                                                                   
  __import__('pkg_resources').require('ms-mint-app==0.3.1.2+5.g4512589')                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                             
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2784, in requires   
    deps.extend(dm[safe_extra(ext)])                                                                                           
KeyError: 'diskcache'                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                               
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                           
                                                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                             
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/bin/Mint.py", line 4, in <module>                                                
    __import__('pkg_resources').require('ms-mint-app==0.3.1.2+5.g4512589')                                                     
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3283, in <module>   
    def _initialize_master_working_set():                                                                                      
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                         
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3295, in _initialize_master_working_set                                                                                                            
    working_set = _declare_state('object', 'working_set', WorkingSet._build_master())                                          
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 589, in _build_master                                                                                                                              
    ws.require(__requires__)                                                                                                   
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 926, in require     
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))                                                                    
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve     
    new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]                                                                         
  File "/Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2786, in requires   
    raise UnknownExtra(                                                                                                        
pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: dask 2024.5.2 has no such extra feature 'diskcache'    

I tried installing `dask[diskcache]' with conda and it worked:
conda install dask[diskcache]
Channels:
 - conda-forge
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Also diskcache package is installed.
 - diskcache==5.6.3
 - dask=2024.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
 - dask-core=2024.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
 - dask-expr=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0

Also tried installing it with pip:
pip install dask[diskcache]
Requirement already satisfied: dask[diskcache] in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2024.5.2)
WARNING: dask 2024.5.2 does not provide the extra 'diskcache'
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.5.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec>=2021.09.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (2024.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: partd>=1.2.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.3.1 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.10.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.13.0 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[diskcache]) (7.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.13.0->dask[diskcache]) (3.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging>=20.0->dask[diskcache]) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: locket in /Users/sdrwacker/miniforge3/envs/mint/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from partd>=1.2.0->dask[diskcache]) (1.0.0)


What code are your trying to run? Did you tried to import dask? This looks like an Python environment issue. Maybe try to upgrade your Python version.

Seemed to be a confused conda env which installed packages all over the place but in the right env.
